# Iterating over lists within a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have written some code to iterate over a list of lists that returns true or false based on if `i` at an index in a list is bigger than all other values `j` at the same index in other lists:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(0, len(list)):
        if (np.any(list[i]) >= np.all(list[j])):
            count = count + 1
            results.append((count == len(list) - 1))

print (results)
```

this works fine in finding the right answer. However, the problem is that the function doesn't iterate over the entirety of the list inside the list like I would hope. For example, from a list like this:

```
list =[[1, 3, 6, 5, 9], [7, 2, 8, 9, 1]]
```

I would expect an output like this:

```
results = [False, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, False]
```

However, it is only iterating over the first two indices and stops.

```
results = [False, True, True, False]
```

I know this is probably because the length of `list` is 2, but I don't have a good solution for getting the function to iterate over the entire list inside the list. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain how you expect the output from the list in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid using Python keywords as variable names (eg: `list`).  But if you calculate the maximum value per column before looping, you can then more easily calculate what you after like this:

#### Code:

```
lst = [[1, 3, 6, 5, 9], [7, 2, 8, 9, 1]]
maxes = [max(x) for x in zip(*lst)]
print([r == m for row in lst for r, m in zip(row, maxes)]
```

Or as a standard `for` loop:

```
result = []
for row in lst:
    for r, m in zip(row, maxes):
        result.append(r == m)
```

#### Results:

```
[False, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, True, False]
```

Comment: Thank you! But I think I'm confused as to how exactly I would incorporate the max values into my loop? in my question I used a slightly simplified example of the comparison I had written

Comment: Thank you! To make sure I understand this, if I were to change my comparison from 
 `if (np.any(list[i]) >= np.all(list[j])):`  to `if (np.any(list[i]) >= (np.all(list[j] * 5))):`, would the corresponding comparison in your solution look like `[r >=  (m *5) for row in lst for r, m in zip(row, maxes)]`? Sorry if that doesn't make sense

Comment: I just tried on a small list `lst = [[1, 4], [15000, 12] ]` where it returns `[False, False, False, False]` even though it should return `True` for 15000...

Comment: There is no way that the row element can be larger than the max.  I would guess you really want `r * 5 >= m` or also written like `r >= m / 5`